# IIS and Tomcat both need to be updated to HSTS

Tags: tomcat, iis, hsts

We have a server which runs on Tomcat and IIS. We did upgrade IIS to use HSTS adding the following parameters

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=*; includeSubdomais: preload

Question: Do we have to add any parameters to Tomcat file in order to resolve the POAM? If yes, what parameters needs to be added to the tomcat web.xml file?

Added parameters on ISS, POAM keeps getting REJECTED

Comment: That depends. Do you want to protect your site or do you just want to pass your audit?

Comment: Depending of the version of TOMCAT..... You could check this URL for TOMCAT > 7 : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html